# Why is every such function constant: $f(x)=f(x^2)$ for $x \in [0,1]$?

Tags: continuity, functional-equations

Let $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $f(x)=f(x^2)$ for all $x \in [0,1]$.

Any hint/idea for proving that $f$ has to be constant?

Comment: Hello, user3051798. Please see [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question) post about how to ask for help with homework. Also, excellent advice on how to ask a good question in general can be found [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By a simple induction we have
$$f(x)=f(x^{1/2})=f(x^{1/4})=\cdots=f(x^{1/2^n})$$
and since $f$ is continuous then
$$f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x^{1/2^n})=f(1)$$
hence $f$ is constant.

Comment: I just want to add that when $x = 0$, it must be $f(0) = f(1)$ by continuity.

Comment: Very nice, Sami!

Answer (score 7):

Note that $f(x) = f(x^2) = f(x^4) = \cdots = f(x^{2^n})$.

If $x \in [0,1)$, we see that $x^{2^n} \to 0$, and by continuity we have $f(x^{2^n}) \to f(0)$, from which we get that $f(x) = f(0)$.

By continuity we also get that $f(1) = \lim_{x \to 1} f(x) = f(0)$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

Note that e.g. $$f(1/2)=f(1/4)=f(1/16)=\dots$$
Then make use of the fact that $f$ is continuous. You can do this any element of $[0,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the hint. Note that for $a>0$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}a^{1/n}=0$. So for $x>0$
$$ f(x)=f(x^{1/2})=f(x^{1/2^2})=\cdots=f(x^{1/2^n}) $$
and then take the limit as $n\to\infty$ and you can finish the rest.

Comment: The limit $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a^{1/n}$ is actually $1$ for any $a > 0$. I do realize that it was an overlook on your part :-)

Comment: I suspect you meant to have $a^n$ instead, as is, the answer is incorrect.

Comment: @copper.hat, It should be $\lim_{n\to\infty}a^{1/n}=1$.